# TToolBar paints incorrectly on non-themed Windows

Tags: delphi, toolbar

It was recently brought to my attention that one of our applications paints incorrectly on non-themed Windows.

Toolbar is built from TSpeedButtons nested in TToolbar which in turn lives inside a page control.

On themed Windows everything looks nice. Well, not nice, but ok.

[image: TToolbar on themed Windows]

On non-themed Windows, however, weird vertical lines appear inside buttons.

[image: Toolbar on non-themed Windows]

I've searched around but cannot find any report of such a problem. (Most probably just my search kung fu sucks.) Does anybody know of a description of this problem or, even better, a fix?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is wrong with these?

Comment: @mj2008: See the "Add", "Edit", "Delete" and "Copy" buttons - they are drawn with vertical line in the middle which should not be there.

Comment: I remember seeing something simlar since some years: Try adding a separator button and toggle its style between tbsDivider and tbsSeparator. In a themed app a line appears or disappears accordingly - with a non-themed app it toggles between one and two lines instead.

Comment: Can't you replace the speed buttons with TToolButtons as a workaround?

Comment: Seems like a bug when the toolbar's `Flat` property is set to `True`. Happens with any non-windowed `TGraphicControl` descendant.

Comment: We have the exact same problem with our internal project management tool, since we switched its builds from Delphi 5 to Delphi 2010. No solution (but didn't look for it either, internal use only).

Comment: This doesn't work in D2007; quite probably it worked in D5.

Comment: Does it manifest on your development machine? Do you have easy access to a machine where the problem manifests? If so simply start commenting-out large sections of code from TSpeedButton.Paint until the vertical line goes away. When that happens you found the buggy code and you'll know what property needs to tweeked (or what code needs to be fixed). I tried putting a large TSpeedButton on a form and running the app without theeming but for me it looked as expected.

Comment: The effect disappears when you replace `CDRF_DODEFAULT` with `CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT` in `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` handling in `TToolBar.CNNotify`. But probably it's more complicated than that, you'd need to investigate all possible combinations with custom drawing and theming.

Comment: @Cosmin This has probably nothing to do with `TSpeedButton`; it affects all (non-windowed) graphic controls.

Comment: Reproduced in D6 and D2010, flat speed button inside flat toolbar.

Comment: @TOndrej, something has to paint those vertical lines, if it's not TSpeedButton it's TToolBar and being Delphi developers we have the sources for both. I know that's what I'd do, I'd try to figure out the *exact* line of code that paints that.

Comment: I can see what's happening, I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: @Cosmin I just meant don't waste your time with debugging `TSpeedButton`, that's all.

Comment: @gabr: TToolbar isn't designed to hold TSpeedButtons. It's designed to hold TToolButtons, which are made to not only sit on a ToolBar, but are specially written to behave correctly on the bar. The issue you're having (particularly with the separators being drawn the way they are) is because you're using the incompatible SpeedButton and separating them with toolbuttons. TSpeedButton works well on a TPanel, and IIRC were designed for just that prior to MS providing the TToolBar/TToolButton pair in ComCtl. A quick test app with both a TToolBar w/TToolButtons and a TPanel w/Speedbuttons will tell.

Comment: `TToolBar.UpdateItem` includes `TBSTYLE_SEP` in `fStyle` for the `TB_INSERTBUTTON` message. That seems to be where the vertical line is. However, I've got no idea how toolbars work!!

Comment: @Ken: Write this as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it. Also, I had good reasons for using TSpeedButton in this app but I forgot what they were - this app was born in 1999.

Comment: @gabr: I forget when MS added the TToolBar to the common controls library. I remember, though, painstakingly building the equivalent with TPanel/TSpeedButton, manually spacing them to produce the separators (or worse, using a small TBevel). Not fond memories, BTW. :)

Comment: @David: `TB_INSERTBUTTON` doesn't apply if you're not using `TToolButtons`. There's no such message generated for `TSpeedButton`. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TToolbar` isn't designed to hold `TSpeedButtons`. It's designed to hold `TToolButtons`, which are made to not only sit on a `TToolBar`, but are specially written to behave correctly on the bar.

The issue you're having (particularly with the separators being drawn the way they are) is because you're using the incompatible `TSpeedButton` and separating them with `TToolButton` separatorss. `TSpeedButton` works well on a `TPanel`, and IIRC were designed for just that prior to MS providing the `TToolBar/TToolButton` pair in ComCtl.

A quick test app with both a `TToolBar` with `TToolButtons` and a `TPanel` with `TSpeedButtons` should see if this solves the problem.

EDIT: Your comment isn't quite correct. :)

[image]

Set the `TToolBar.AllowTextButtons` to True, and then set the button's you want wider to style `tbsTextButton`. As you can see, I've used a plain button, a separator, a text button (with text and image), a separator, and another plain button.

Comment: TToolButton indeed works but has another problem - changing a width of a TToolButton changes widths of all other buttons on the same toolbar,  which is in my case completely unacceptable.

Comment: @Sertac: I don't understand your comment. Those are just images I grabbed from one of the Glyfx image folders and threw into an imagelist for testing. The capture was taken on WinXP using Delphi XE. I didn't try to do anything with the images - that wasn't the point of the answer (or related to the question in any way).

Comment: @Ken - I know it's not related with the question. I vaguely recall a "black background" image problem in the forums, it's only that I hoped it is not an issue for Gabr to switch to toolbuttons. I was not criticizing the answer, AAMOF I voted for it. :)

Comment: @Sertac: Just making sure I wasn't missing something. IIRC, there's an issue with PNG image transparency, `TImageList`, and WinXP, but that's not what I was looking into. :) Thanks for the vote. :)

Comment: @Ken: Thanks for that addition to your answer. Maybe now I'll change my app to use TToolButtons.

Answer (score 2):

As TOndrej said in comments, this happens when `TSpeedButton.Flat` and `.Transparent` are both set to True. As David found out, `TToolbar` must also have `.Flat` set to True for the problem to occur.

A workaround that doesn't require changing the VCL source code is to set `.Transparent` to False.

Comment: I didn't mention `Transparent` but you're right, setting it to `False` does help. No themes, Windows XP, Delphi XE. +1 for a simple workaround.

Comment: Very ugly workaround. How about stop using TToolbar with speed buttons.  Doesn't require changing the VCL source code either. If you want a panel with speed buttons, then use a panel with speedbuttons, and forget about toolbars.

Comment: @Warren: Not ugly. On non-themed Windows, transparency doesn't do anything useful anyway.

Comment: There are more problems with putting speed button controls into Toolbars than just this funny line rendering and the transparency issue.

Comment: @Warren: Never run into any and the app is alive 12 years.